# How to use Slingshot.fileRestrictions to only allow zip files to be uploaded?

Tags: meteor, meteor-slingshot

i found the code below in slingshot source code

```
Slingshot.fileRestrictions("myFileUploads", {
  allowedFileTypes: ["image/png", "image/jpeg", "image/gif"],
  maxSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024 // 10 MB (use null for unlimited).
});
```

they show how to limit the upload to images, how do i only allow .zip files to be uploaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a file upload happens the package uses what is in allowedFileTypes and calls a function in the Slingshot package called [`Slingshot.Validators.checkFileType`](https://github.com/CulturalMe/meteor-slingshot/blob/master/lib/validators.js) to validate the File object's MIME type against (`File.type`).  Based on a [list of MIME types](http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/mime-types-complete-list/) for .zip files, you want to allow the following:

- application/x-compressed
- application/x-zip-compressed
- application/zip
- multipart/x-zip